# Selenium(grid?) FitNesse Maven Jetty

Tags: maven, selenium, fitnesse

heres the problem:

Maven takes 20 mins to build my project, 18mins being the fitNesse integration tests.

The tests are run by starting a Jetty server locally and then firing fitNesse tests one by one.

I've heard that Selenium-grid can run multiple tests at the same time. Maven has a Selenium plug-in and I've seen that Selenium can run fitNesse tests.

But I can't find information about connecting all three?

Basically, I would like to run my existing fitNesse tests through Selenium aimed at a local Jetty server to parallelize them in Maven.

Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: How about http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/05/10/maven-based-automated-execution-of-fitnium-acceptance-tests/?

Comment: Thanks! thats definitely more than I've managed to find. Doesn't mention running tests in parallel though...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TestRunner class.

TestRunner will read the Fitnesse Tests entries from text file

TestRunner will create threads and run Fitnesse Tests in threads using Trinidad : Inprocess test runner for Fitnesse wiki

http://www.fitnesse.info/trinidad

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import fit.Counts;
import fitnesse.trinidad.*;
import java.io.*;

public class InProcessRunner {
public static String testright, testwrong, testexceptions, testname,summary;
public static Counts cs;
public static int right, wrong, exceptions, totalright, totalwrong,
        totalexceptions;
public static String str1, strhead , strsummary;
static UUID batchId = UUID.randomUUID();

public static void startProcessing(final List<String> tests)
        throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        try{
            for (String next : tests) {         


                String dbhost = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/automation?user=root";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();           
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbhost);  

                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.executeQuery("select * from environment");     

                ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();

                      while(rs.next()){

                      System.setProperty("browser", rs.getString("browserCode"));               



                      boolean status = new File("C:\\wamp\\www\\output\\"+ batchId +"\\"+ rs.getString("browserName") +"").mkdirs();    
                      System.out.println(status);
                       TestRunner tdd = new TestRunner(new FitNesseRepository(
                            "C:\\root\\fitnesse"), new FitTestEngine(),
                            "C:\\wamp\\www\\output\\"+ batchId+"\\"+rs.getString("browserName")+"");

                    cs = tdd.runTest(next);
                    right = cs.right;
                    wrong = cs.wrong;
                    exceptions = cs.exceptions;
                    totalright = right + totalright;
                    totalwrong = wrong + totalwrong;
                    totalexceptions = exceptions + totalexceptions;


            testname = tests.toString();
            testname = testname.replace("[", "");
            testname = testname.replace("]", "");
            summary = cs.toString();


            java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
            java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);

            String sql = "insert into report(testName,passed,failed,exception,createdTime,batchId,browser) values ('"+ testname +"','"+ right +"','"+ wrong +"','"+ exceptions +"','"+ currentTime  + "','"+ batchId +"','"+ rs.getString("browserName") +"')";
            System.out.println(sql);
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            System.out.println(sql);                    

            ps.execute(sql);
            ps.close ();                


            System.out.println(" Test Passed " + totalright);
            System.out.println(" Test Failed  : " + totalwrong);
            System.out.println(" Test Exceptions  : " + totalexceptions);
            }

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
}   

    };
    t.start();

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("C:\\root\\fitnesse\\TestList1.txt");


    try {
        BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String csvline = null;

        int c = 0;
        List<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((csvline = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
            if (c == 1) {
                startProcessing(testList);
                testList = new ArrayList<String>();
                c = 0;
            }
            testList.add(csvline);
            c++;
        }
        startProcessing(testList);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could tie the three together with jenkins, replacing maven with jenkins. I wrote a short blog about it http://mjvdende.com/2013/05/execute-xebium-fitnesse-tests-on-your-own-selenium-grid/

The idea is simple. Let Jenkins control you selenium grid through the selenium plug-in and the execute your fitnesse tests in jenkins with the fitnesse plug-in

hopes this helps

Comment: For those who are interested: this is the new [link](http://mjvdende.com/2013/05/execute-xebium-fitnesse-tests-on-your-own-selenium-grid/) http://mjvdende.com/2013/05/execute-xebium-fitnesse-tests-on-your-own-selenium-grid/